# Showing 1-10 from 56 items

Tags: grammaticality, phrase-usage

I have a grid displayed in my app, and the app can show 10 rows of data at a time. At the bottom of the grid it provides buttons for left and right to browse through the data.

What is the best wording for letting the user know which rows are being shown?

Currently I have:

> BackBtn-NextBtn **Showing 1-10 from 56 items**

Please let me know if the above is correct or what's a better way to express it.

Comment: The preposition normally used is _of_, not _from_.

Comment: If you are being very explicit in the wording, I would replace the dash with "to": *Showing 1 to 10 of 56 items*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options:

- Record: |< < 1-10 of 56 > >|
- Row: |< < 1-10 of 56 > >|

Comment: How is this answering the OP's request for _verbiage_??

Comment: How is it not? I have graphically represented the situation described in the question with two choices of the correct wording. As Janus says in the comment - "The preposition normally used is of, not from".